# Re order array index before submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays, laravel-5

```
<input type="hidden" name="gallery[0]" value="gallery-image-1500382700392.jpeg">
<input type="hidden" name="gallery[1]" value="gallery-image-1500382700392.jpeg">
<input type="hidden" name="gallery[2]" value="gallery-image-1500382700392.jpeg">
```

This is the form elements.In my admin panel i have the facility to delete images in the art gallery.If I am deleting name="gallery[2]" element, data saved to database is

```
["gallery-image-1500382700392.jpeg", "gallery-image-1500382700392.jpeg"]
```

and the format is json array

But if Iam deleting name="gallery[1]" element, data saved to database is of json object format.

```
{"0": "gallery-image-1500295044382.jpeg","2": "gallery-image-1500295044382.jpeg"}
```

I think this is because array indexing is not there [0,1] so treated as just key-value pair

I there any way to re-order this indexing?

Comment: try using array_values to the array you are getting after submitting form

Comment: yes its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reset the keys of an array and Return all the values of an array.

Here is example,

```
<?php
$a = array(
3 => 11,
1 => 22,
2 => 33,
);
$a[0] = 44;

print_r( array_values( $a ));
==>
Array(
  [0] => 11
  [1] => 22
  [2] => 33
  [3] => 44
)
?>
```